# Mongodb indexing long paragraph values

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, nosql

Is it recommended to index a field/key which is actually a paragraph(value).

e.g: { Name: xxxxx
       org: xxxx
       instruction: "Long Paragraph"
     }

Is is ok to index the instruction field which could be a 2 line paragraph using 3.2.8 mongod server?
Also i shall be having around 10,000 documents in the collection each doc has this instruction field and the docs are embedded with multiple documents.

Comment: What kind of operations do you need to perform with this field?

Comment: FIND & UPDATE are the operators i need to perform on this field

Comment: You will perform searching by this field with text search operator (`$text`) or with standard equation, or may be with regexp (`$regex`)?